# Cocoa touch SDK 3.2 - How to play video

Tags: ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using MPMoviePlayerViewController in SDK 3.2 for iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218158/using-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-in-sdk-3-2-for-ipad)

How do I play video on SDK 3.2 (iPad)?

Read many questions here but they talked mostly for iPhone.
For example, the MoviePlayer example here http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html

That works on 3.1.3 but when I run it on 3.2, it doesn't work.

So basically I'm able to play a video on 3.1.3 using this code but the same code won't run on 3.2

NSString *moviePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Movie.mp4"];

```
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]];

moviePlayer.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeDefault;

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];

[moviePlayer play];
```

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 1):

MPMoviePlayerController doesn't work on the iPad anymore - only audio is played.  You have to use MPMoviePlayerViewController to get the correct functionality

[Using MPMoviePlayerViewController in SDK 3.2 for iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218158/using-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-in-sdk-3-2-for-ipad)

Thanks for the update Apple :(

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. Here is how:

```
NSURL* videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
MPMoviePlayerController moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
[moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[moviePlayer play];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
```

Thanks,
Tee