# videos play on iPhone but not on iPad with SDK 4.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming

Hi I have several apps using a MPMoviePlayerController.  These apps play HTTP Live streaming video fine when compiled with the older SDKs but with 4.1 on the iPad (3.2) the apps will only play audio and the standard controls are not showing.  On iPhone devices (any version) it plays the videos just fine.

The code looks like this:

```
mMoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:mediaURL];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:mMoviePlayer];   
    mMoviePlayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
mMoviePlayer.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeDefault;
    [mMoviePlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out - now you have to use MPMoviePlayerViewController

[Using MPMoviePlayerViewController in SDK 3.2 for iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218158/using-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-in-sdk-3-2-for-ipad)

Thanks for the update Apple.  :(