# MPMoviePlayer sample doesn't work

Tags: xcode, ios, sample, movieplayer

I wish I could have found this solution when I googled every possible combination of these words.

Did you, like me, think you could download Apple's Movieplayer sample, click Build and Run and see a movie of an airplane?  And nothing happens, right?

Here is the solution:
[Using MPMoviePlayerViewController in SDK 3.2 for iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218158/using-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-in-sdk-3-2-for-ipad/4291028#4291028)

Comment: I guess I could have said "why doesn't the sample work?"

Answer (score 1):

Because the [MoviePlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html) demo is very old (2009-05-03) and because Apple is too lazy to update their code to support new approach on iOS 3.2/4.0.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this http://iosdevelopertips.com/video/getting-mpmovieplayercontroller-to-cooperate-with-ios4-3-2-ipad-and-earlier-versions-of-iphone-sdk.html

It works both for new and old devices.