# can we add mpmovieplayerviewcontroller as a subview?

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to play a video on a same view on a button click.

```
NSURL *movieUrl = @"Some Url";
            CGRect frame;
            frame =CGRectMake(10,10,100,100);
            MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieUrl];
            [self.view addSubview:player.view];
            player.view.frame = frame;
            [player release];
```

when I run this, it shows a frame with black background but does not play the video. I am not using youtube video.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSURL* videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
MPMoviePlayerController* mPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
[mPlayer prepareToPlay];
[mPlayer play];

//For viewing partially.....
[mPlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 200, (self.view.frame.size.width)-100 , 400)];
mPlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]; 
[self.view addSubview:mPlayer.view];
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to call:

```
[player play];
```

Second, releasing the player will most likely stop playback immediately.  You need to hang onto that player elsewhere and release it when the movie finishes playing.

Comment: Thank for the reply.When i write [player play] the app crashes.give me solution.Please

Comment: i found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218158/using-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-in-sdk-3-2-for-ipad