# Add video to an iPad application

Tags: ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using MPMoviePlayerViewController in SDK 3.2 for iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218158/using-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-in-sdk-3-2-for-ipad)

I am writing an application for iPad. till now I have a splash screen then a home screen. Home screen has 6 buttons. Pressing a button on the second or home screen takes you to the third screen which has two options a)Play Video b)read document. Now if play video is pressed it plays the video corresponding to the button pressed on second or home screen. similarly for the Read document, it opens a pdf file respective to the button pressed on home screen. Now I want to add video and pdf to those screens. how can i do it?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Best Regards
Prateek

Comment: You want to play video separately and read pdf separately then I can suggest you something useful, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just load the files into `UIWebView`, it can handle both videos and PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

To play the video use the movieplayer framework form apple. Have a look into the sample code from apple here
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/index.html
To read the PDF document and having some gestures for page turn use the following sample code form github:
https://github.com/brow/leaves